# Writing in memory XSSFWorkbooks to in memory zip

Tags: java, excel, java-io, zip

I am reading db records and creating in memory XSSFWorksbook.

Once this is done, I am writing this workbook to zip output stream. The zip is created properly, but xlsx file isn't generated property. In place of excel it creats folders and files like _rel, worksheets, sharedStrings, styles and workbook.xml

```
//Read records from db and create workbook
public static XSSFWorkbook buildReportDocuement(int reportIndex,
    List<Object> result) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet(REPORT_NAME_PREFIX);
    setExcelHeader(excelSheet);
    processActivityReportData(result, excelSheet);      
    return workbook;
}

//reading worksbooks into bytearray and addign to in memory zip files
public static ByteArrayOutputStream zipWorkbooks(
    List<XSSFWorkbook> workbooks) throws IOException {

    int workBookIndex = 1;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Reports");
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

    for (XSSFWorkbook current : workbooks) {
        zipEntry = new ZipEntry(REPORT_PREFIX + workBookIndex
            + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
        zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        current.write(byteOutputStream);
        if (byteOutputStream != null) {
            zipEntry.setSize(byteOutputStream.size());
            zipOutputStream.write(byteOutputStream.toByteArray());
            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
        }
    }
    zipOutputStream.close();
    return byteOutputStream;
}
```

I am not supposed to write any of the files to file system. Please guid me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Finally I have figured out. The issue was with my logic. I miss understood the concept of ByteArrayOutputStram. I have made changes to the function zipWorkbooks and it worked perfectly. The changes are:

public static ByteArrayOutputStream zipWorkbooks(
      List workbooks) throws IOException {
      int workBookIndex = 1;
      ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ByteArrayOutputStream workbookByteArrayStream= null;
      ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteOutputStream);
      ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

```
  for (XSSFWorkbook current : workbooks) {
     zipEntry = new ZipEntry(REPORT_PREFIX + workBookIndex
        + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
     zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
     workbookByteArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     current.write(workbookByteArrayStream);            
     zipEntry.setSize(workbookByteArrayStream.size());
     zipOutputStream.write(workbookByteArrayStream.toByteArray());
     zipOutputStream.closeEntry();          
  }     
  zipOutputStream.close();
  return byteOutputStream;
```

}